# No responde mi boton para agregar un producto

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, livewire

estoy aprendiendo a usar livewire y estoy haciendo una tienda online. no logro hacer funcionar mi boton de agregar producto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al hacer Click deberia agregar un producto.

```
    <div wire:ignore.self>

    <div style=" box-shadow: 0 0px 0.9px rgb(0 0 0 / 7%), 0 0px 7px rgb(0 0 0 / 14%);"
        class="list-unstyled w-100  rounded d-flex  align-content-center">
        @forelse ($results as $post)

        <div class="w-25"><img style="height: 100px; width: 100px; objet-fit:cover;" class="" src="{{ $post->imagen}}"
                alt=""></div>

        <div class="w-70 mr-4 text-left pl-4 pt-1">
            <li style="    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 600;
    background-color: white;
    color: #4c4c4c;"> {{ $post->nombre }}</li>

            <li> $ {{ $post->precio }}</li>



        </div>


        @livewire('products',['productoid'=>$post->id])

        @empty
        <li>No hay resultados para "{{ $search }}"</li>
        @endforelse
    </div>
</div>
```

El componente que utilizo se llama **products**

```
    <div>
  
        <button  wire:click="addToCart({{$productoid}})">+</button>
 <div>
```

Controlador:

```
  public function addToCart(Request $request)
    {

        dd($request);

        Cart::add([
            'id' => $request->id,
            'name' => $request->name,
            'price' => $request->price,
            'quantity' => $request->quantity,
            'attributes' => array(
                'image' => $request->image,
            )
        ]);
 
    }
```

En el controlador deje un dd($request); para ver si llegaba el id del producto pero no reaciona, no hace nada.

**porque sucede esto?**